Using Pipes for Stream Data in FFMPEG
I am trying to input stream and decrease the bitrate of the video without saving it anywhere so i am hoping to pass it as a stream and get the output as a stream and send it to digital ocean spaces to get saved.
But I tried lots of things but my output Stream is getting empty. and the file is empty.
    public async Task VideoOperationAsync(Stream inputStream)
    {
        try
        {
            // Ensure the input stream is at the beginning
            inputStream.Position = 0;

            // Create a memory stream to hold the output data
            using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var arguments = $"-i pipe:0 -f mp4 pipe:1";

                await Cli.Wrap("ffmpeg")
                    .WithArguments(arguments)
                    .WithStandardInputPipe(PipeSource.FromStream(inputStream))
                    .WithStandardOutputPipe(PipeTarget.ToStream(outputStream))
                    .WithValidation(CommandResultValidation.None)
                    .ExecuteAsync();

                // Ensure the output stream is at the beginning before reading
                outputStream.Position = 0;

                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"D:\Gremlin-data\VideoResized\output_cropped.mp4", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    await outputStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            throw;  // Re-throw the exception if needed
        }
    }

I also earlier tried this:
public async Task VideoOperationAsync(Stream inputStream)
{
try
{
// Ensure the input stream is at the beginning
inputStream.Position = 0;
        var ffmpegProcess = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "ffmpeg",  // Ensure ffmpeg is in your PATH or provide the full path
                Arguments = $"-i pipe:0 -b:v 2000k -f mp4 pipe:1",  // Correct bitrate format
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,  // Capture standard error
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };

        ffmpegProcess.Start();

        // Write input stream to ffmpeg's standard input asynchronously
        Task writingTask = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await inputStream.CopyToAsync(ffmpegProcess.StandardInput.BaseStream);
            ffmpegProcess.StandardInput.BaseStream.Close();
        });

        // Read ffmpeg's standard output to a memory stream asynchronously
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Task readingTask = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await ffmpegProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyToAsync(ms);
            });


you are using ExecuteAsync, and you are not awaiting this call. It might be the issue why your file (so also the stream) end up being empty.

i added await but still the length is 0 and ouput is empty

That's interesting, however, i dont see that outputStream is being given as ref parameter- in that case it should be output parameter. Is Cli.Wrap returning something? If you dont pass parameter by ref forsure it wont get updated, or to say it more precisely- you wont get a result in the place that you're calling this method.

Also, are you sure there is something in the input stream? You get it from somewhere, do you check if anything is inside ?

Yes i checked the inside of inputStream and it had data.

Cli.Wrap basically does the piping for you and puts the output data in the output stream after executing the arguments

Then i see no reason in the code you posted. Maybe input stream is just empty? Can you check that ?

Yes I did it had data, now I have resorted to saving it in temporary file and deleting afterwards.
